# Convert tally table to a table

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have a table in Google sheets which approximately looks like this:

| Name | Red | Yellow | Green | Blue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | 1 |  |  |  |
| John |  | 1 |  |  |
| Steven |  |  | 1 |  |
| Bill |  |  |  | 1 |

I want to shorten it into this kind of table:

| Name | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | Red |
| John | Yellow |
| Steven | Green |
| Bill | Blue |

What formula should I use for the color column?

Answer (score -1):

Would you mind using Excel Power Query?

If not, I suggest you select the first table, and go to Data tab > Get & Transform Data group > From Table/Range.

Select the columns of colors, click Transform tab > Any Column group > Unpivot Columns.

[image]

[image]

Then you may click File > Close and Load to, load the table to one worksheet.